# Jasper Reports: using aggregate results in a calculation

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm creating a summary report in Java using Jasper Reports where information on logs (trees) and their prices is displayed. I want to show the price per thousand board feet for each species. The calculation for this is: cost * 1000 / netFootage. The data is supplied as a list of JavaBeans.

Problem: the resulting price/MBF is not correct, as demonstrated by doing the math using the cost and netFootage shown below.

The only way around this that I've been able to come up with is performing the summary calculations outside of Jasper Reports, and that's a headache I'd rather not suffer if I don't have to.

Here is the report:
[image: Jasper Inventory Summary Report]

EDIT:
If I change from using the fields cost and netFootage to using the variables cost1 and netFootage1, I get this result, which is different... but still wrong.
[image: Jasper Inventory Summary Report with Variables]

This is the full inventory.jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-01-04T19:33:33 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ScaleSummary" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="099eaac8-9789-4d24-96ed-6a0a1a8abbbe">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="reportDate" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="species" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="netFootage" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="overheadCost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="cost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="netFootage1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Species" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{netFootage}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="species1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Species" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{species}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="priceRate1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Species">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}.multiply(new BigDecimal(1000)).divide( $F{netFootage} )]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="cost1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Species" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="overhead1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Species" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{overheadCost}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="lineTotal1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Species">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{cost1}.add( $V{overhead1} )]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="species2" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{species}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="netFootage2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{netFootage}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="priceRate2" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}.multiply(new BigDecimal(1000)).divide( $F{netFootage} )]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="overheadCost1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{overheadCost}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="cost2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="lineTotal2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{cost1}.add( $V{overhead1} )]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Species">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{species}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="15">
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" printWhenGroupChanges="Species" uuid="1123bb45-40fd-4fc9-a5f1-2e976d1a3f99">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{species}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="190" y="-1" width="70" height="15" uuid="b655bef4-dcf0-4e3a-818d-8383020f3e8c"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{netFootage1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="80" height="15" printWhenGroupChanges="Species" uuid="db90f3b9-aca4-4ab5-97b0-48c9dfda815f"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{species1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="Species" pattern="¤#,##0.000;¤-#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="80" height="15" printWhenGroupChanges="Species" uuid="8188363f-3984-4b11-bfcf-c99cf65c8a61">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{priceRate1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="Species" pattern="¤#,##0.##;¤-#,##0.##">
                    <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="8a707e2f-3e22-46d7-a833-f95a3538541c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{cost1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="¤#,##0.00;¤-#,##0.00">
                    <reportElement x="420" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="a345cd4e-32b5-4bd6-bb89-d3064bbe4042">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{overhead1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="¤#,##0.00;¤-#,##0.00">
                    <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="70" height="15" uuid="5679a2ee-43dd-4e52-9915-0da8b2788cfc">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{lineTotal1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="95" splitType="Stretch">
            <image hAlign="Center">
                <reportElement x="0" y="-2" width="580" height="50" uuid="93bfff74-d6ee-4b94-a5b8-4db39f4515d5"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["images/title.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="190" height="20" uuid="614fca9d-ef2c-4930-aa6b-0b4be9e88bea"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Current Inventory Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="445" y="80" width="125" height="15" uuid="2f423025-4158-42ad-b5bc-29aec3d63ee2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="354" y="80" width="91" height="15" uuid="2dbec0c0-05cc-46f5-bf36-d92609e5c152"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Report Date:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="570" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a18f566c-5972-43f5-8754-00a46cdf262f"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="100" height="20" uuid="d839c8d1-ff31-4aa0-a0ea-d0d57780f919"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Species]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="70" height="20" uuid="b6a482c2-52e7-4e87-b4e1-cd59a605964d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Cost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="420" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="dcdaf6e6-d07a-4d59-a702-2ca5ee0e2667"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Overhead Cost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="0064bc76-4f28-4fcd-a6a4-a0021e37c329"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Cost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="a5e40833-70bc-4afa-a16e-33f7bd9225a5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$/MBF]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="80325097-ad9c-4cb7-8f1d-cd28e508b85b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Net BFt]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="b4bc60d0-fac0-48c0-8db3-f7cae8abbbf0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[# of Logs]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="81" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="570" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="2815f185-79f9-4c63-9c3e-a26d889e290c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" uuid="31141427-83b2-49f4-8edc-d238fdcfb701"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Totals: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="baa57730-fef0-4194-a2a0-1fb67428615b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{species2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="190" y="0" width="70" height="15" uuid="e9fc1f24-c4d8-430e-a9ed-15874c450c15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{netFootage2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤#,##0.000;¤-#,##0.000">
                <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="673065c9-010a-40ac-bae0-3286df02b659"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{priceRate2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤#,##0.00;¤-#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="420" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="a96091a6-d61a-4624-aa5b-49fe00cdde75"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{overheadCost1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤#,##0.##;¤-#,##0.##">
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="1530dda8-714f-48e8-886c-66e1c0122c65"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{cost2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤#,##0.00;¤-#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="70" height="15" uuid="57e3165b-60cc-4e08-bf71-9b9b3681219c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{lineTotal2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Try convert cost & netFootage to BigDecimal by doing new BigDecimal( $F{cost}) & new BigDecimal( $F{netFootage})

Comment: You're showing `netFootage1` in your report but you're using `netFootage` in your calculation. `netFootage1` is an aggregate. The $/MBF for the items with only one log are ok (within rounding error) so it looks like the problem is here, you should be making your calculation over the same netFootage as the one the you're displaying.

Comment: @digit, cost and net footage are already defined as BigDecimals. Creating new BigDecimals from them has no effect.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt see the edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a glitch. I threw out the jrxml file and started from scratch. The results under the new jrxml were correct when I used cost1 and netFootage1.

Although the .jrxml files were identical, the first version gave me garbage results, while the second version gave me the correct information.